# How to add datetime.time to datetime.datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have both a Python `datetime.datetime` object and a `datatime.time` object and am looking for a way to add the time to the datetime object.

A simple addition doesn't seem to be supported. The time is essentially representing a duration.

Comment: *Add* as in *addition*? Then you want a `datetime.timedelta`, not a `datetime.time`.

Comment: Yes, add as in addition. It is coming from a database I cannot influence, and is unfortunately a `datetime.time` object.

Comment: Is the "datetime" entry from the database actually just a date with "0:00:00" time? Ie, is it just a date being converted to a `datetime` object?

Comment: @aneroid no, its actually a full datetime object including a time. Its essentially a starting date / time (datetime) and a duration of the event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi let's suppose that you have an instance `t` of class `datetime.time` and an instance `dt` of class `datetime.datetime`:

```py
new_dt = dt + datetime.timedelta(hours=t.hour, minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second, microseconds=t.microsecond)
```